# (React-Native) Set Cookie doesn't work in IOS, but perfectly on Android

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cookies, webview

**Problems**

I'm using react-native for our current services, and we are sending cookies to our webpage to send information which is needed to seen in our webview. These process is working PERFECTLY in android devices, but not in IOS. (The most annoying thing is set-cookie works sometimes in IOS in same condition. It just randomly succeeded, and I cannot find the reason why.)

**How To Reprouce**
First of all, these are the stacks we are currently using.

- Application: React-Native
- Webview: react-native-webview (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)
- Cookie: @react-native-cookies/cookies (https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies)
- Webpage: React (Already deployed in AWS)
- Cookie: react-cookie (useCookie)

And the following is our process we are currently doing.

1. If the user clicks a button (I will call this button as 'Apply' button), it navigates to screen that includes <WebView />
2. This is a abstract of our webview screen code (For our security issue, I just abstracted and changed some code for it, so if you think more information for our code, please let me know.)

- Rendering Page
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oB63.png)

  - WebView Component
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLgG7.png)
- Send Cookie
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcmqO.png)
- Send Cookie Function
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCnWk.png)
  (This function is kinda messy bc this is a collective code from 3 files, and I tried my best to set cookie differently with android. (The same logic with android doesn't work in IOS))
- Webpage (Launched in AWS)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgWRc.png)

**I Want My Code To Do This**
I want my code to send cookie in loading state, and after loading, when the webview rendered, the webpage get some cookie and based on that cookie, it shows some data.

It PERFECTLY works on Android, but not in IOS. It works randomly in IOS so I have no idea what the heck is wrong with this code and hard to define a problem.

**I tried...**

1. Someone said to me to add '.' infront of domain. It worked for the very first time, but after the second trial, it starts to not working again
2. I also tried clear all cookie data before set cookie using

```
 await CookieManager.clearAll();
```

, but it works same as the first measure I tried.

3. I also tried to use webkit. I send all true arguments to use webkit while using cookiemanager, but it has no effect.

**I expected to do...**

As I write in the above, I hope the cookie is rightly set in both android and ios environment, perfectly works in both platform.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.